# extjs6 display files in network folder on server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, extjs

Using extjs, is there a way to show files in a network folder on the server?  This is only for a webclient and the webserver being on the same internal company network.

In the webapi I did something like this (below), and in debugger mode it does see the folder... but how would I go about listing all the files in this folder in some type of list... possibly a popup window.  Similar to someone actually clicking on a folder in windows explorer.

The eventual goal would be to click on one of the files, and it opens in the webpage.

```
DirectoryInfo _dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\xxx\xxxxxx\Contacts\Clients\xxx\target");
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: apologies, from the webbrower, is it possible to have a popup window launched in extjs to show files in a network folder